# Hiding #DIV/0! in cells with conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a cell with conditional formatting and this formula:

```
=IFERROR((F31-E31)/E31,"")
```

That works fine and replaces #DIV/0! with "" when E31 is blank. However, when that condition is true I lose the border of my cells. See picture:

[image: Blank border on cells]

My conditional formatting rules just set a highlight fill color for the cell, I didn't mess with the border (pretty sure). Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Please add screenshots of your rule definitions.

Comment: Are those actually grey outlines on those cells or are they just Gridlines (View -> Show -> Gridlines) ? I suspect the latter, if that is correct, add an outline to the conditional format

Comment: Gridlines are not shown on cells with fill color. That includes cells filled as white. Manually fill a single cell as white to see this effect.

Comment: @FlexYourData https://ibb.co/SfmTW0q https://ibb.co/hYhk9mC. I am choosing 'no fill color', not a white fill color. But it appears to me as if I am removing the gridlines just like a white fill color would. Also under View -> Show -> Gridlines, Gridlines is checked

Comment: Just remove the rule for when the cell is blank. It doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: The reason I have the rule is because when IFERROR rule is true and it enters "" into the cell, the other rule is activated for some unknown reason (and the cell is highlighted red). Why would "" activate a rule that is supposed to activate when the value > 0.05? That doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text - [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Add the same border (or a simulated border) to the conditional formatting (border AND fill can coexist).

Comment: There is no border on the normal cells. It's just the default gridlines which vanish when the conditional formatting rule is true. The lines shouldn't vanish in my opinion because I'm just telling the cell to have no fill color (not a white fill color)

Comment: What one would consider "normal" is not valid for Excel. It has some more strange idiosyncrasies.